# How to bind nested vuex object to vuejs property in tiptap text editor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, tiptap

I'm trying to bind the nested Vuex state object to *editor* property of tiptap's *editor-content* component.

The state looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <table
    :style="{ backgroundColor: element.options.backgroundColor }"
    class="main"
    width="100%"
    cellspacing="0"
    cellpadding="0"
    border="0"
    align="center"
    style="display: table;"
    data-type="title"
  >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
             class="border-9/5 border-dashed border-transparent hover:border-blue-200"
            :class="{
              'border-builder-blue shadow border-dashed cursor-auto hover:border-builder-blue':
                element.active,
              'cursor-pointer': !element.active,
            }"
          >
            <div
              :align="element.options.align"
              :style="{
                paddingTop: element.options.padding[0],
                paddingRight: element.options.padding[1],
                paddingBottom: element.options.padding[2],
                paddingLeft: element.options.padding[3],
              }"
              style="color: #757575;"
              data-block-id="background"
            >
              <editor-content :editor="computedEditor" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import { EditorContent, Editor } from 'tiptap';

export default {
  components: {
    EditorContent,
  },
  props: ['element'],
  data() {
    return {
      content: null,
      options: {},
      id: '',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    computedEditor: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.email.editors[0].editor;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('email/testEditorUpdate', value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Store in nuxt framework.

```js
import { ELEMENTS_DATA, DEFAULT_OPTIONS_DATA, ICONS_DATA } from '../components/editor/editor.data';

export const state = () => ({
  testEditor: null,
  currentElement: null,
  currentEditor: null,
  editors: [],

  elements: [],
  html: '',
  emailSettings: {
    options: {
      paddingTop: '50px',
      // paddingLeft: '5px',
      paddingBottom: '50px',
      // paddingRight: '5px',
      backgroundColor: '#EDF2F7',
    },
    type: 'emailSettings',
  },
});

export const getters = {
  getEditorById: (state) => (elementId) => {
    debugger;
    const { editor } = state.editors.find((editor) => editor.elementId === elementId);
    return editor;
  },
};

export const mutations = {
  addNewElement(state, newElement) {
    if (Array.isArray(newElement)) {
      state.elements.push(newElement[0]);
    }
    state.elements.push(newElement);
  },
  addNewEditor(state, newEditor) {
    state.editors.push(newEditor);
  },
  updateElements(state, elements) {
    state.elements = [...elements];
  },
  setCurrentElement(state, element) {
    if (state.currentElement) {
      state.currentElement.active = false;
    }
    state.currentElement = element;
    state.currentElement.active = true;
  },
  setCurrentEditorById(state, id) {
    state.currentEditor = state.editors.find((item) => item.elementId === id);
    state.currentEditor.editor.options.editable = true;
  },
  updateCurrentEditor(state, editor) {
    state.currentEditor.editor = { ...editor };
  },
  testEditorUpdate(state, editor) {
    state.editors[0].editor = editor;
  },
  setEditable(state, id) {
    const currentEditor = state.email.editors.find((item) => item.elementId === id);
    currentEditor.editor.options.editable = true;
  }, 
  toggleElementActive(state, element) {
    element.active = !element.active;
  },
};
```

The nested vuex object is located in editors array in vuex store shown in picture below.

[image: Vuex store structure img]

If I do this approach, then I get this error log of vue. When I did it via vue data properties, it was working like a charm but the upgrade to vuex is quite problematic to me and I don't know why.

```
client.js?06a0:97 Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?2f62:135)
    at Vue.store._vm.$watch.deep (vuex.esm.js?2f62:889)
    at Watcher.run (vue.common.dev.js?4650:4563)
    at Watcher.update (vue.common.dev.js?4650:4537)
    at Dep.notify (vue.common.dev.js?4650:741)
    at EditorView.reactiveSetter [as _props] (vue.common.dev.js?4650:1066)
    at EditorView.update (index.es.js?576a:4594)
    at EditorView.setProps (index.es.js?576a:4607)
    at Editor.setParentComponent (tiptap.esm.js?cd42:1296)
    at VueComponent.eval (tiptap.esm.js?cd42:1604)
_callee$ @ client.js?06a0:97
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:293
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:118
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21
eval @ client.js?06a0:59
globalHandleError @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1875
handleError @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1844
run @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:4565
update @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:4537
notify @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:741
reactiveSetter @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1066
update @ index.es.js?576a:4594
setProps @ index.es.js?576a:4607
setParentComponent @ tiptap.esm.js?cd42:1296
eval @ tiptap.esm.js?cd42:1604
eval @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1985
flushCallbacks @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1911
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1938
nextTick @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1995
Vue.$nextTick @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:3520
computeIndexes @ vuedraggable.common.js?310e:2229
realList @ vuedraggable.common.js?310e:2198
run @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:4563
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:4307
eval @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1985
flushCallbacks @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1911
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1938
nextTick @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1995
Vue.$nextTick @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:3520
emit @ vuedraggable.common.js?310e:1969
dispatchEvent @ sortable.esm.js?aa47:916
_dispatchEvent @ sortable.esm.js?aa47:961
_onDrop @ sortable.esm.js?aa47:2166
handleEvent @ sortable.esm.js?aa47:2269
client.js?06a0:97 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2149)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
    at _traverse (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2151)
```

Comment: please share the store code

Comment: I've already edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. The main problem was that the Vuex could not work with large object structures and my object editor contained many of functions and nested configuration subobjects and arrays. There are two ways to solve this.

1. Change the structure of the vuex object
2. Make a deep clone of the object in mutations in Vuex store.